# The model editor imports my model as a block

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

If I go to the model editor and imports a previously saved model (or any existing model) it is being imported as a single model instead of a group of parts that can be selected individually. If I click the model there is no "Open link editor" option, just copy and delete.

I'm using gazebo8 nightly: `7.99.00+hg20160430rb016c48c553c-1~wily`

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/13205/the-model-editor-imports-my-model-as-a-block/) by [Jose Luis Rivero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/152/jose-luis-rivero/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1485 on 2016-05-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

This is because is being imported as a model so it can be used in model nesting or other operations. To get access again to the parts the following actions needs to be performed:

- Exist the Model editor to the simulation window
- Insert your model
- Select it, right click, edit model

And all the links and joints appear again as when you initially created the model.

---

Originally posted by [Jose Luis Rivero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/152/jose-luis-rivero/) with karma: 1485 on 2016-05-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1